# Oracle 11g. Unable to import dump files, even though schema is created

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have created a user in Oracle 11gR2, using the following script

```
create user          cata
identified by        cata
default   tablespace tbs
temporary tablespace temp;

grant DBA to cata;
```

After trying to import a dump file using the command

```
impdp system/password@ORCL11 schemas=cata dumpfile=cata.dmp logfile=log.txt
```

i'm getting the following error

**ORA-39002: invalid operation
ORA-39165: Schema ATGDB_CATA was not found.**

Surprisingly, when i try to export a dump from the same schema, i'm able to do that. So, if the schema was not created properly then i should not be able to export the dump file as well, right ?

I have also checked in dba_users & the schema is created.  Is there anything else that i can do which could resolve this problem

Answer (score 11):

Out of the error message I guess that the original schema name was "atgdb_cata".

As you are now trying to import into a schema named "cata" you need to specify the parameter `remap_schema`

So for your case: 
`impdp system/password@ORCL11 schemas=atgdb_cata dumpfile=cata.dmp logfile=log.txt remap_schema=atgdb_cata:cata`

Comment: Thanks for your reply GWu. It turns out that i didn't receive the correct schema names. The dump file had another schema name & i was using a different one.

Answer (score 0):

Grant the roles of read and write on the Directory in which you created to the New User: EX:

```
GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY dir_name TO NEW_USER:
```

Also grant the following role to the new user:

```
GRANT IMP_FULL_DATABASE TO NEW_USER;
```

Thanks!
NC

Answer (score 0):

ORA-39002: invalid operation
ORA-39070: Unable to open the log file.
ORA-29283: invalid file operation
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 536
ORA-29283: invalid file operation

SOLUTION:
create or replace  directory test_ dir as  'FOLDER_NAME' ;

that 'FOLDER_NAME' must has that dump file

step : 1
create folder SAMPLE under orcle_installed_path/sql/SAMPLE
put that dump file into that SAMPLE folder.

go to bin and execute ./sqlplus
and login
SQL>create or replace  directory test_ dir as  'SAMPLE' ;

SQL> SQL>  GRANT READ, WRITE on directory test_dir to 'USER';

SQL> GRANT IMP_FULL_DATABASE to 'USER';
exit
then impdb to import that dump